# Cloud Run Service requests always fail with 401 when using JWT returned for another service. The same request works with JWT returned for end-user

Tags: jwt, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-iam

I have an app consisting of multiple **Cloud Run Services**. Each service is open only to a specific set of other services.

Let's say I have 2 services with URLs `https://api-service-123.run.app` and `https://data-provider-service-123.run.app`. The first service also has a custom URL `https://api.my.domain`.

**api-service** needs access to **data-provider-service**. So, following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service), I created two per-service user-managed service-accounts **api-service-account@domain** and **data-provider-service-account@domain**. I added *api-service-account@domain* into *data-provider-service* with **Cloud Run Invoker** role.

Now, I have trouble accessing the account with ID Token returned from Google. I tried several ways. Firstly, I utilized slightly adjusted code from the docks

```
export const getToken = async (url: string, targetAUD?: string) => {
    const auth = new GoogleAuth();
    const request  = async () => {
        if (!targetAUD) {
            targetAUD = new URL(url).origin;
        }
        console.info(`request ${url} with target audience ${targetAUD}`);
        const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAUD);
        const res = await client.request({url});
        console.info(res.data);
        return res.data;
    }
    try {
       return await request();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

When the function above is called as `getToken('http://data-provider-service-123.run.app');`, the request fails with **401 Unauthorized**.
I also tried to call it as `getToken('https://data-provider-service-123.run.app');` and got a response **403 Forbidden**. The following entry is added to *data-provider-service* logs for each such request

```
    {
    httpRequest: {9}insertId: "60fcb7e0000c12346fe37579"
    logName: "projects/my-project/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"
    receiveTimestamp: "2021-07-25T01:01:20.806589957Z"
    resource: {2}
    severity: "WARNING"
    textPayload: "The request was not authorized to invoke this service. Read more at 
     https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating"
    timestamp: "2021-07-25T01:01:20.800918Z"
    trace: "projects/my-project/traces/25b3c13890aad01234829711d4e9f25"
    }
```

I also tried to obtain and use JWT from **compute metadata server** (also a way advertised in the docs) by running `curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=http://data-provider-servive-123.run.app" \ -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`.

When I execute this code in **Cloud Shell**, I get JWT that looks like this

```
{
"iss": "accounts.google.com",
"azp": "123456789-9r9s1c4alg36erliucho9t52n12n6abc.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"aud": "123456789-9r9s1c4alg36erliucho9t52n12n6abc.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"sub": "106907196154567890477",
"email": "my_email@gmail.com",
"email_verified": true,
"at_hash": "dQpctkQE2Sy1as1qv_w",
"iat": 1627173901,
"exp": 1627177501,
"jti": "448d660269d4c7816ae3zd45wrt89sb9f166452dce"
}
```

Then I make a request using postman to `https://data-provider-service/get-data` with a header `Authorization: "Bearer <the_jwt_from_above>"` and everything **works fine**

However, if I make the same request from my `api-service`, the JWT returned is

```
{
"aud": "http://data-provider-service-123.run.app",
"azp": "111866132465987679716",
"email": "api-service-account@domain",
"email_verified": true,
"exp": 1627179383,
"iat": 1627175783,
"iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
"sub": "111866132465987679716"
}
```

If I make the same request with the postman and place this JWT into the Authorization header, the 401 Unauthorized is returned.

I have spent this week trying to solve this issue. I triple-checked the permissions, redeployed the services several times, but nothing helps.

Comment: The problem is the incorrect `aud` (audience). Compare the working token with the failing one.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I'm not sure, but I guess the audience from the working token refers to the scope of the entire project, as I get it from Shell while having the Owner permissions.  Actually, I wonder why the working JWT has a broader aud than requested, but it's another question. I guess this quote from docs supports my thoughts
 "_Fetch a Google-signed ID token with the audience claim (aud) set to the URL of the receiving service._"

Comment: The `aud` for the working Identity Token is `"aud": "http://data-provider-service-123.run.app",`. Do you notice what that represents? That is the service that you are calling. If the audience is wrong, permission denied.

Comment: @JohnHanley,
Conversely, the working token obtained from Shell is ```123456789-9r9s1c4alg36erliucho9t52n12n6abc.apps.googleusercontent.com```. And the aud of not-working token matches the _data-provider-service_, yet it returns 401.

Comment: Simplify your question to a) show the code; b) show the decoded token; c) show the exact call using the token using a tool such as `curl`; d) show the error. Your other code that works is not helpful. Something is wrong in the information you have included which is confusing/masking the real problem. In other words, start over with a concise problem that I can reproduce.

Comment: Note: You can use one service account to call any number of other services. It is the identity of the service account that grants access, not uniqueness.

Comment: @JohnHanley, excuse me if my exposition is confusing. There is a single place in the code that fails. This is the `getToken(url, targetAUD)` function, which is mostly a copy of the code from docs. This function is called as `getToken('http://data-provider-service-123.run.app');` within `api-service` and returns 401 error. I tried to work around this by replacing **google-auth-library** with axios request to **compute metadata server** within `getToken` function. It works and returns me a JWT with targeted service as **aud**. Still, the service rejects the token with a 401 response.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comments, the audience is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I changed http to http**s** in the URL of the target service when asking **computing metadata server**, and looks like it solved the problem. Requesting token like this with **google-auth-library** still fails with **403 error**.

I'll update that answer if the solution is sustainable.